# tk.entry unable to .get() input in another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to understand how tkinter .entry works.
I want the user to put in some text, then when enter is pressed it will check a dictionary for the text and return relating dictionary results.

```
def enterhit(event):
    populate_ISBNs()

def populate_ISBNs():
    print("You hit return.") 
    print(sku.get()) #this should print what is in the entry box

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Label(self, text="SKU").grid(row=1)
        sku = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1) #this is the entry field
        tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=populate_ISBNs).grid(row=1, column=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")

    root.bind('<Return>', enterhit)

    root.mainloop()
```

When enter or the 'Search' button is pressed then it should print "you hit return." followed by what was typed into the entry named 'sku'

It prints "you hit return" but also prints "type object 'Page1' has no attribute 'sku'"

Comment: What is `Page`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add and define a textvariable the entry

```py
sku_var = tk.StringVar() # Define textvariable
tk.Entry(self, textvariable=sku_var) # Set textvariable
```

at the populate_ISBNs() take it to the class itself
make it

```py
class Page1(Page):
    sku_var = tk.StringVar() # Define textvariable
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Label(self, text="SKU").grid(row=1)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.sku_var) # Set textvariable
        tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=populate_ISBNs).grid(row=1, column=2)

    def populate_ISBNs(self):
        print("You hit return.") 
        print(self.sku_var.get()) #this should print what is in the entry box
```

(Edit)
and also you should not define the Entry variable since you are using OOP ( Object-Oriented Programming )

Comment: I made the changes inside of the class Page1:
`sku_var = tk.StringVar()   
tk.Entry(self,textvariable=sku_var)   
tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=populate_ISBNs)`   

 then changed the reference to `print(Page1.sku_var.get())`
however I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Added another edit which is as I think would help you and make it oriented

Comment: Have tried your method but now I get the error 'name 'populate_ISBNs' is not defined'  
I then tried to move the populate_ISBNs() above init but the same error occurs.

Comment: There's really no need to use a textvariable. You can, but it adds an extra object you need to manage. You can get and set the value of an Entry without having an associated variable.